# Please give some approach to achieve the data set for the following data set

Tags: mysql

In my table there is 5 distinct event 1,2,3,4,5. In attendee column there are attendees who attained these events. and in isThisuserHost column there is 0 and 1 flag. 1 for host who host the event and 1 for attendee who attain the event.I need to show the event where host is 2 and attendee is 4. In this table we can see that event 1,2,and 4 is those rows where host is 2 and attendee is 4. How to extract the result using a single query?

[image: My Table]

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem,kindly mark it as an answer and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select distinct eventid
from mytable m1
where 2 in (select attendee
            from mytable m2
            where m2.eventid = m1.eventid
            and isTheuserHost = 1
           )
and   4 in (select attendee
            from mytable m3
            where m3.eventid = m1.eventid
            and isTheuserHost = 0
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a selfjoin here:

```
select h.eventId
from myTable h
join myTable a using(eventId)
where h.isTheuserHost = 1
  and a.isTheuserHost = 0
  and h.attendee = 2
  and a.attendee = 4
```

`h` and `a` are different aliases for the same table. `h` stands for hoster and `a` for anttendee with the corresponding condition for the `isTheuserHost` column. Then you can use that table as if it were two.